# Angular routing Issue (Caching)

Tags: angular, caching

I created an angular application that has three login pages for three modules called live, planning, and corporate. The default loading login page related to the corporate module. But I need to navigate to other login pages by typing their URLs in the same browser tab. Following are the URLs of three login pages,

```
  http://localhost:3000/#/auth/login

  http://localhost:3000/#/auth/login/live

  http://localhost:3000/#/auth/login/planning
```

But when I try to navigate by typing other URLs in the same browser tab it does not redirect to the other login pages but **it works on three different browser tabs**.

*For example, if you  access the Corporate module login page (default one), then log out, and try to access the Planning module by typing the Planning URL same tab, it still redirects to the Corporate module login page.*

These are the routes

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: NbAuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: NbLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: NbLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'login/live',
        component: NbLiveLoginComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'login/planning',
        component: NbPlanningLoginComponent,
      },
    ];
  },

 { path: '', redirectTo: 'auth/login', pathMatch: 'full'  },

];
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the pathMatch full strategy? You can look it up here: https://angular.io/api/router/Route
Also it might be helpful if you posted your routes.

Comment: I added the routes

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a child route, angular tries to render the specified compontent into the parent component. So you would have to set another "router-outlet" in every parent component in which you want the children to get loaded.
Maybe this routes would do what you want:

```
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: NbAuthComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'auth/login',
    component: NbLoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'auth/login/live',
    component: NbLiveLoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'auth/login/planning',
    component: NbPlanningLoginComponent,
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'auth/login', pathMatch: 'full'  }
```

If you want all your components to get loaded into the NbAuthComponent, you would set all the other components to children of you NbAuthComponent.